# How to run webdriver.io synchronously?

Tags: node.js, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, webdriver-io

[webdriver.io's what's new in v4.0](http://webdriver.io/guide/getstarted/v4.html) docs says "It's all synchronous...All commands now block the execution of the test process until they’ve resolved."

The only example I can find of synchronous WebDriver code is:

```
browser.url('/');
var title = browser.getTitle();
```

When I execute something similar (via `note test.js`, not `wdio`):

```
var webdriverio = require('webdriverio');
var options = {
  desiredCapabilities: {
    browserName: 'chrome',
    logLevel: 'silent'
  }
};

const driver = webdriverio.remote(options)
driver.url('http://www.google.com')
const title = driver.getTitle()
console.log('title', title)
```

...title is `title { state: 'pending' }`, indicating it's a promise.  How can I convince this to operate in synchronous fashion, ideally without having to use async / await?

Comment: I may be mistaken, but it looks like the article says it's all synchronous for testing only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you start your browser

```
const client = webdriverio.remote(options).init()
```

there is a well known problem with webdriver.io and chrome browser which is not part of this awnser but the result will aswell explain your question. Chrome is freezing on low hardware pc´s and if you run a webdriver.io command until chrome is fully load your script crash. A workaround is to make this as example:

```
 client
 .url('http://localhost/dashboard')
 .waitForVisible('body', 20000000).then(function(isExisitingLOCALHOST){
    //.. you may add here aswell a timeout if your hardware is really low and has really long freezing.

              client
              .url('http://yourwebsite.com') // <-- webdriver.io will wait until your loading icon from the tab is ready. This means at ajax websites you must build aswell a workaround with the waitForVisible() endpoint. As example waiting for a specific item to load logo, text etc.
              .click('#sample')

  })
```

With this small workaround you can make sure to dodge the freezing of your browser at the startup process and wait until it´s done. This explain aswell the sync writing way with webdriver.io

you could make in a endless sync way your webdriver.io API endpoints:

```
client
.click()
.pause(1000)
.rightClick()
```

Also very important to know that pause() is really buggy at some points and it will not be sync, sometimes it´s not working.. You should use the basic setTimeout from javascript instead.

You can also write this way

```
client.getText('#sample1');
client.getText('#sample2');
```

to process multiple api endpoints next to each other.